# Remove comment section from new page

Tags: pages, comments, page-template

I am taking over a wordpress website at work. All of the pages currently do not have a 'Leave a Reply' comment section. When I make a new page, this section exists on the new page. How do I remove it? As far as I can see all of the options as far as the page goes are the same.

I have already tried to uncheck 'Allow people to post comments on new articles' but it didn't do anything

Comment: This really depends on how the current pages are set up. Are they using templates (under Page Attributes in admin)? Has the 'Allow comments' checkbox been unchecked on a case by case basis? Are they using page specific templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be rid of comments on your site, one option is to remove the code from your theme files.

You would need to search single.php, home.php, page.php, *etc.* within
 `wp-content/themes/*your-active-theme*`  and find:

```
<? php comments_template(); ?>
```

Remove that and the comments section should disappear.

*NOTE:  this change will be undone if you update the theme files.  Modifying a child-theme is a much better practice.*